# After uploading a premium theme, Magento website doesn't work although admin dashboard is working fine

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, google, google-cloud

I'm a bit new to php and trying to install Magento 2.1.6 with a premium theme. I'm using GCP, using their Marketplace solution for Magento.

After I upload theme to Magento root (copying app, pub and lib folders), I ran below commands in the root without any error.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

I gave following permissions

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Now, after all these steps I'm able to see admin dashboard but I get the error below when I open the main site. Can anyone please help me what can be wrong here, I tried multiple times to copy the files from the premium theme and reinstalled it many times but end result is always this.
Has anyone faced similar issue before? do you think I'm missing anything?

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Framework\View\EntitySpecificHandlesList does not exist

Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Framework\View\EntitySpecificHandlesList does not exist
#0 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#3 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#4 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#5 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...')
#6 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/PageFactory.php(55): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory->create(true)
#9 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\View->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag))
#10 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#13 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'view', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#14 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#16 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#17 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#18 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#21 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/Base.php(300): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#22 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#23 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#27 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#30 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#33 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#36 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#39 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#42 {main}
```

Comment: You have issue on MGS_Mpanel module's a block class.

Comment: @AmitBera I think its not off topic but its related to general issues of theme installation on Magento

Comment: @AmitBera eventually it came as a bug from a theme provider

Answer (score 4):

Please follow below step:

```
1) rm -rf var/generation var/view_processed/ var/di/ var/cache/ var/page_cache
2) rm -rf pub/static/frontend/  pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/
```

And after that run upgrade and deploy command.
Don't forget to give proper permission as below:

```
chmod 777 -R pub/static/  var/
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I tried with above commands as well and still getting the same error. I cleared cache as well after running upgrade and deploy command and also gave the permission.

Comment: Are you provided 777 permission for generation folder and run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command also. It is a permission issue.

Comment: when I ran `setup:di:compile` I'm getting below error 
` [RuntimeException]   Class Magento\Framework\View\EntitySpecificHandlesList does not exist`

Comment: Just to give you an update, there was this compatibility issue from the Theme provider with Magento 2.1.6. They are going to release the new patch for this issue.