# Class not found error while compiling Magento

Tags: magento-2.1, php, cloud, google

After I copied files for a new Theme, I was able to upgrade and deploy but when I open the main site it is throwing me

```
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Framework\View\EntitySpecificHandlesList does not exist
```

When I ran compile command I'm getting the following error. This is continuation of the issue [After Theme Installation Main site is down](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237003/after-uploading-a-premium-theme-magento-website-doesnt-work-although-admin-das)

**Updated with Error Stack trace**

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 12 secs 164.0 MiBMiB8.0 MiB

  [RuntimeException]                                                     
  Class Magento\Framework\View\EntitySpecificHandlesList does not exist

Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Generator.php:70
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Generator->generateList() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Interception.php:100
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Interception->doOperation() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:187
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php:96
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/bin/magento:23
```

Comment: Is your theme compatible with the version of magento 2 your using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 2.1.6 and I'm taking the corresponding lib, app, pub folders for this version from the theme

Comment: Which deploy mode are you using - developer or production?

Comment: Check file/folder permissions once

Comment: @VivekKumar I am using developer mode, I also tried with default mode before but still the same error

Comment: @inrsaurabh I've set all the permissions correctly

Comment: refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Class EntitySpecificHandlesList comes from version 2.2.x and doesn't exist below 2.2.x. So definitely it would be the exception.

Comment: Its a bug in the theme and they are going to update with a new patch, but you are right somewhere it is calling this class from Magento 2.2.x